# How to use the OAuth Class in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, oauth

I'm trying to add the OAuth class in codeigniter but when i call it's show error

> Non-existent class: OAuth

**This is my code**

```
class Food extends My_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->library('OAuth');
    }
    public function get_yelp_api(){

    $unsigned_url = "http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/the-waterboy-sacramento";
    $consumer_key = '***********';
    $consumer_secret = '**********';
    $token = '***************';
    $token_secret = '**************';

    $token = new OAuthToken($token, $token_secret);

    $consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);

    $signature_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();

    $oauthrequest = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($consumer, $token, 'GET', $unsigned_url);

    $oauthrequest->sign_request($signature_method, $consumer, $token);

    $signed_url = $oauthrequest->to_url();

    $ch = curl_init($signed_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($data);
    $json_string = file_get_contents($signed_url);
    $result = json_decode($json_string);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}

}
```

I also try to add it on this way

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/OAuth.php');
```

but still got an error

> Non-existent class: OAuth

Comment: Have you got an oauth library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you doing mistake loading a class as library load it like this

> Non-existent class:OAuth

**solution**

just only need to load class at the top of controller like this:

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/OAuth.php');
```